# Hide Android action bar?

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I hide the Android action bar on certain activities such as a splash screen? I've tried changing the theme, but it changes the whole applications theme. Also leading me to some place that could help me would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way is to add `@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` to your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.package.Activity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
```

or you can add this line in your Activity `onCreate` function

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

there also third way to do that, it's like the first one but instead of using predefine theme you can create your own custom theme and use it

in `style.xml` something like this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
   <!-- this style parent may change by any defined theme you want -->
</style>
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and use your theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.package.Activity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme" >
```

Comment: Note that this will force the specific theme you choose in your manifest xml if you use the xml approach.

Comment: The "third way" works the best for me. It preserves all the other style attributes and only changes the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Put the NoActionbar derived theme on the `activity` not the `application` in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate of your activity add this line before setContentView(....):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: So this is the Java way?

Answer (score 0):

On the latest version of documentation I found this for Android Kotlin:

```kotlin
private fun hideSystemBars() {
  val windowInsetsController =
      ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
  // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
  windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
      WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
  // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
  windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive